# Changing a char in a char list list using SML

Tags: list, types, sml

I'm trying to declare a function that will let me change a number in a char list list (I'm still working on the sudoku game from earlier). 
changesudo : char list list -> int * int * char -> char list list
I need to be able to call changesudo xs (r,s,c) where xs is the char list list, r is the list, s is the position in xs and c is the char.

This is what I have:

```
fun changesudo xs (r,s,c) = 
                            let 
                              val g = hd (List.take (List.drop 
                                                     (xs , (r-1)) , 1)); 
                              val h = (List.take(g , s-1)) @ [c] 
                                      @ List.drop(g , s);
                            in
                              (List.take (xs , (r-1)) @ [h] @ List.drop(xs , r)) 
                            end;
```

and this is a 'a list list -> int * int * 'a -> 'a list list - so I'm almost there.

How do I fix it?

I get the char list list with [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918288/turning-a-string-into-a-char-list-list-using-sml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to fix. The type you've got is more general than the type you aimed for, but that's not a problem.

The type `'a list list -> int * int * 'a -> 'a list list` works perfectly well to change a character in a `char list list`. All it means is that you could also use it to change an integer in an `int int list`.

In other words: if you put in a `char list list` and a `char * int * int` tuple, you'll get out a `char list list` with the char at the given position replaced, so it works exactly like you want.

One word of caution: I don't know whether it's intentional or not, but your function is 1-indexed, i.e. the first item in the first list is at position `(1,1)` not `(0,0)`.

Comment: For the fun of it I put this in: val x = getsudo xs and now I get this: val aendrsudo = fn : string -> int * int * char -> char list list (and changed the xs to x in the function).
Do you know of any way of forcing it to be a char list list -> int * int * char -> char list list? This is homework and they want it to have this type.

Having the function be 1-indexed would mean that I start with (1,1) meaning list 1, position 1 - and that makes more sense to me than starting from line 0.

Comment: @George: You can just put an explicit type annotation somewhere, like `fun changesudo xs (r, s, c:char) = ...`. However there really is no need to do that, as it will work exactly the same. I doubt your instructors will mind if your function has a more general typed than was asked for.